# indexOf is not a function - Angular 2 / Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Scratching my head over this...

I have a function called **filterProducts** that is called in my Angular 2 component anytime a user clicks a checkbox. For now, the method finds all checkboxes that are checked with a specific class name, gets their values, and then attempts to sort an array. Fairly simple...

```
// Called when any checkbox is checked or unchecked

filterProducts() {

// Grab all "Program" checkboxes that are checked
var programsToInclude = $(".programCheckbox:checkbox:checked").map(function () { return this.value; });

// If any "Program" checkboxes are checked, filter the list accordingly
if (programsToInclude)
    this.filteredProducts = this.filteredProducts.filter(x => programsToInclude.indexOf(x.programName) > -1);
}
```

Why am I getting the following error?

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: programsToInclude.indexOf is not a function
```

programsToInclude is definitely a string array, which should have this function, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`programsToInclude` isn't an array, it's a jQuery object. jQuery objects have a lot of array methods, but not all.

To get an array after using `jQuery#map`, you need to tack a `.get()` on the end:

```
var programsToInclude = $(".programCheckbox:checkbox:checked").map(function () { return this.value; }).get();
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^
if (programsToInclude) { // <== This check is pointless, see below the fold for why
    this.filteredProducts = this.filteredProducts.filter(x => a.indexOf(x.programName) > -1);
}
```

Alternately, use `get` early to get a native array, which requires adjusting your `filter` call:

```
var programsToInclude = $(".programCheckbox:checkbox:checked").get().map(function(e) { return e.value; });
// -----------------------------------------------------------------^^^^----------^-----------^
if (programsToInclude) { // <== Again, see below the fold
    this.filteredProducts = this.filteredProducts.filter(x => programsToInclude.indexOf(x.programName) > -1);
}
```

In both cases, though, `programsToInclude` ends up being an array. If you want to use it as a jQuery object again later, you have to convert it back. If you do want to use it later, you might have the array separate:

```
var programsToInclude = $(".programCheckbox:checkbox:checked").map(function(e) { return e.value; });
if (programsToInclude) { // <== Same note
    let a = this.programsToInclude.get();
    this.filteredProducts = this.filteredProducts.filter(x => a.indexOf(x.programName) > -1);
}
```

---

Why the check is pointless: A jQuery object, even an empty one, is always truthy. If you want to check for an empty one, use `if (obj.length)`. But there's not much point in such a check if you're about to do `filter`, `filter` is a no-op when the object is empty anyway.